# altering envelope's namespace while sending SOAP request from a client created by svcutil

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have several SOAP web services that have the same interface but have different URLs' and namespaces'.

URL 1 http://badservice.com/one has a namespace "one-ns"
URL 2 http://badservice.com/two has a namespace "two-ns"

When I generate a web service client via svcutil from http://badservice.com/one?wsdl, I can only use it for http://badservice.com/one. Once I try to send a request to http://badservice.com/two SOAP service says

```
namespace mismatch require http://nanopetdbs.driver.maestro.ibtech.com found http://ozkaraslanpetroldbs.driver.maestro.ibtech.com
```

I can generate clients for each web service URLs at the worst scenario.

I need an idea to prevent code duplication in this case. I have tried altering namespace while sending requests, could not make it.

I need to change the highlighted place of the envelope **at the runtime**.

[image]

Comment: update: I have failed to implement a generic code with svcutil generated client. instead I have used another library to implement generic mechanism: https://github.com/pmorelli92/SoapHttpClient/tree/master/Source/SoapHttpClient

Answer (score 0):

No, we can’t specify these values at the runtime. During `SOAP` communication, this field will be used for addressing the method to be called.
Here is a communication telegram captured by Fiddle.
[image]
The SOAPAction field will specify the method to be called.
If these values can be changed at the runtime, the addressing method becomes confusing. This is the meaning of a service contract with its namespace and name properties.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace ="http://mycommany.com")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(Name ="Mymethod")]
    Int32 Add(Int32 Num1, Int32 Num2);
}
```

Besides the BasicHttpbinding, some other bindings, such as wshttpbinding using ws-addressing. They use these properties(namespace, name) in `Action SOAP header` to specify the addressing method.
[image]
In summary, It is these attributes that determine the addressing mode at the runtime, so we cannot modify these attributes(namespace, name) at the runtime.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.